# How to extract title inside span h5 a href link using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract the title of a link using BeautifulSoup. The code that I'm working with is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import pandas as pd

hdr={'User-Agent':'Chrome/84.0.4147.135'}

frame=[]

for page_number in range(19):
    http= "https://www.epa.wa.gov.au/media-statements?page={}".format(page_number+1)

    print('Downloading page %s...' % http)

    url= requests.get(http,headers=hdr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

    for row in soup.select('.view-content .views-row'):

        content = row.select_one('.views-field-body').get_text(strip=True)
        title = row.text.strip(':')
        link = 'https://www.epa.wa.gov.au' + row.a['href']
        date = row.select_one('.date-display-single').get_text(strip=True)

        frame.append({
        'title': title,
        'link': link,
        'date': date,
        'content': content
    })

dfs = pd.DataFrame(frame)
dfs.to_csv('epa_scrapper.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

However, nothing gets displayed after I run the above code. How can I extract the value stored inside the title attribute of the anchor tag stored in link?

Also, I just want to know how can I get append "title", "link", "dt", "content" into a csv file.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the link text, you can use selector `"h5 a"`. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import pandas as pd

hdr={'User-Agent':'Chrome/84.0.4147.135'}

frame=[]
for page_number in range(1, 20):
    http= "https://www.epa.wa.gov.au/media-statements?page={}".format(page_number)

    print('Downloading page %s...' % http)

    url= requests.get(http,headers=hdr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

    for row in soup.select('.view-content .views-row'):

        content = row.select_one('.views-field-body').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
        title = row.select_one('h5 a').get_text(strip=True)
        link = 'https://www.epa.wa.gov.au' + row.a['href']
        date = row.select_one('.date-display-single').get_text(strip=True)

        frame.append({
            'title': title,
            'link': link,
            'date': date,
            'content': content
        })

dfs = pd.DataFrame(frame)
dfs.to_csv('epa_scrapper.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Creates `epa_scrapper.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I'm quite new to Python, so I'm a bit messed up. Thank you so much really!